# Does Promise.race ignore promises after the first promise resolves

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, promise

[image: code snippet]

I have this code snippet, the timeoutPromise is supposed to resolve after 250ms IF the responsePromise does not resolve in that amount of time. Right now I see the timeoutPromise resolves regardless of the responsePromise.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The image isn't necessary for your question, you'd be better off removing it, and then maybe adding 4-5 lines of code that is your promise situation *below* the text portion of your question.

Comment: Promise.race doesn't prevent losing promises from finishing, it simply resolves it's own promise with the result of the first promise that completes.

Comment: Please do NOT post code into images, ever.  Post it as text so we can copy/paste it into answers, so we can copy paste it into an editor to run it, etc...  You just make it difficult for people to write meaningful answers when you post it in images.  Not to mention, it's hard to read on mobile, can't be indexed, isn't friendly to the visually impaired, etc...  Don't post code in images, ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `Promise.race()` does it report to the caller which of the promises you passed it resolved/rejected first.  It does not affect whether they resolve/reject and does not stop the other promises from resolving after the first one has resolved.  The operations in those other promises still keep going and they have whatever outcome they would have, regardless of using `Promise.race()`.

Look at this example which you can run right in the snippet:

```js
function resolveMs(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`resolveMs(${ms}) resolving`);
            resolve(ms);
        }, ms);
    });
}

console.log('Starting...');
Promise.race([resolveMs(100), resolveMs(50), resolveMs(200)]).then(result => {
    console.log(`Final result: ${result}`);
});
```

That generates this output:

```
resolveMs(50) resolving
Final result: 50
resolveMs(100) resolving
resolveMs(200) resolving
```

There you can clearly see that all three promises resolve on their expected schedule.  `Promise.race()` itself resolves when the first of the three promises you passed it resolve, but that does not affect the other two operations.  They keep doing what they were doing.

You can think of it like an 800m running race.  `Promise.race()` reports the winner of the race (that is its job), but just because there's a winner, the other participants don't stop running.  They still finish the race too in whatever time they would have if they ran on their own.

If you want the other operations to somehow stop when the first resolves, you'd have to manually code things so that you cancelled the other two operations and they would have to represent operations that are cancellable as there is no automatic, built-in mechanism for stopping asynchronous operations that are already underway.  In my example above, one would have to call `clearTimeout()` on the remaining timers (and you would have to save the timerID values somewhere so you could call `clearTimeout()` on them).